# How do I extract make-3.81.tar.gz?

Tags: make

I am new at Linux, and am currently using Ubuntu in a dual-boot with windows 7. I'm trying to install Make such that I can build a program given to me with it. I can SEE the make-3.81.tar.gz, but don't know how to extract it

For reference, I have this file in /host/Linux/Make

*EDIT* I do not have internet access on this computer

Comment: `make` is available in the official Ubuntu repositories. Run `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to install the basic compiling tools.

Comment: Euhm... Why is the Ubuntu `make` not good enough for you? You really don't want to install GNU make from source, really. Just do `sudo apt-get install make`? or install from Software Centre. Pro tip: install `build-essential` for all build-related tools.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the two comments, you do not need to install your own `make` program, unless you are looking for a particular version or brand. Most of the tools you need to build your programs are already in the main distribution.

Since you do not have internet access from your Ubuntu installation, and I assume that you are downloading your programs from another computer, you need to search for the correct `.deb` package in the Ubuntu repositories. Since I do not know your system version, I cannot give you a link.

However, if you insist on using the make that you have on your computer, you can either just double-click on the file and then extract the archive, or open a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) and type

```
cd /host/Linux/Make/
tar xzf make-3.81.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

This version of *make* is available in Ubuntu.

## How to check whether make is installed or not?

Just type this into the program "terminal" and press enter:

```
make --version
```

It will tell you the version of your current installed make or tell you it is not installed.

## It's not installed. What now?

What you did was downloading the source code. So apparently you do have internet somewhere else. So just download this file, it's the binary (compiled) version of make from the official Ubuntu repository: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/make-doc_3.81-5.1_all.deb

Copy it on your computer, double click on it and click on Install. It's easy!

## I really just want to extract this file!

In this case it does not really make sense, but just to give the information:

**Extracting in file browser**

Right click on the file and click on *extract here* (or similar, I'm using Ubuntu in german).

**Extracting via terminal**

use the command *cd* to go to the correct folder:

```
cd /host/Linux/Make
```

and then extract the file:

```
tar xzf make-3.81.tar.gz
```